# .XML - .XSD How to reference XML file with Schema XSD file?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd, dtd

Every time I try and validate it says No DTD or XSD assigned to doc. Both files are local.

.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com">

<xs:element name="jobList">
 <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:element ref="job"/>
   </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="job">
 <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="resource"/>
    <xs:element ref="problem"/>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element ref="work"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="status" use="required">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="unallocated"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="allocated"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="completed"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="confirmed"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="resource">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="manufacturer" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="serialNumber" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="employeeId" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="problem">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="reported" type="xs:dateTime" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="work">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="technician"/>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="note"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="jobId" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="technician">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="allocated" type="xs:dateTime" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

And the .XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jobList xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="jobList.xsd">

<job status="unallocated">
    <resource employeeId="AD145267" type="Laptop">
        <manufacturer>Dell</manufacturer>
        <model>Vostro 1540</model>
        <serialNumber>764839211-19-H</serialNumber>
    </resource>
    <problem reported="2012-01-22T15:23:00">Fails to boot</problem>
</job>

<job status="unallocated">
    <resource employeeId="TE135218" type="Wireless printer">
        <manufacturer>Epson</manufacturer>
        <model>Stylus SX435W</model>
        <serialNumber>E4356-982312</serialNumber>
    </resource>
    <problem reported="2012-01-23T10:07:00">No wireless access</problem>
</job>

<job status="allocated">
    <resource type="Network drive">
        <manufacturer>G-Tech</manufacturer>
        <model>G-RAID Hard drive array</model>
        <serialNumber>783451287G</serialNumber>
    </resource>
    <problem reported="2012-01-24T11:02:00">Read errors reported during  rebuild</problem>

    <work jobId="564">
        <technician allocated="2012-01-24T15:05:00">T541</technician>
        <note>Spoke to Eric about what happened.</note>
        <note>Ran phase 1 diagnostics - no errors reported</note>
    </work>
</job>

</jobList>
```

I will also link the dtd file (incase you find it useful)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
TODO define vocabulary identification data
PUBLIC ID  : -//vendor//vocabulary//EN
SYSTEM ID  : http://server/path/__NAME__
-->
<!-- LEVEL 1 (ROOT) ELEMENT  -->
<!ELEMENT jobList (job)*>

<!-- lEVEL 2 ELEMENT -->
<!ELEMENT job (resource, problem, (work)?)>
<!ATTLIST job status (unallocated|allocated|completed|confirmed) #REQUIRED>

<!-- lEVEL 3 ELEMENTS -->
<!ELEMENT resource (manufacturer, model, serialNumber)>
<!ATTLIST resource
employeeId CDATA #IMPLIED
type CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT problem (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST problem reported CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT work (technician, (note)*)>
<!ATTLIST work jobId CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!-- lEVEL 4 ELEMENTS -->
<!ELEMENT manufacturer (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT serialNumber (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT technician (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST technician allocated CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT note (#PCDATA) >
```

I managed to successfully validate the DTD with XML (but I removed the reference), but I'm struggling to get the XML to link to the XSD. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema defines `targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"` and so instead of [noNamespaceSchemaLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256139%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need to reference the XSD using the [schemaLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256100%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com jobList.xsd"

Things to consider:

- you could reference multiple XSDs for multiple namespaces; form a pair for each, as shown above.

And

> According to the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) XML Schema
>   Recommendation, XML instance documents can have both
>   xsi:schemaLocation and xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attributes
>   specified. In addition, you can list the same namespace several times.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, it still notifying me with no DTD or XSD relationship...Do you have any other ideas on what the issue could be? In the mean time I will try it in a different editor to see if it's XMLpad that's behaving oddly

Comment: I've tested it in a different application and it's validating... How odd. Thank you for your help Petru!

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file you have xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
but in your XSD file you have xmlns="jobList.xsd" and targetNamespace="jobList.xsd"

They need to be the same

Comment: Would I link it all to the .xsd file?

Comment: I've tried both combos (switching it round) at it still giving me the same error message